# Получить название метода объекта из кода

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в коде метода объекта класса языка JavaScript получить название вызываемого метода?

Comment: Дайте пример, где такая надобность существует. Напрямую, похоже, что нет.

Comment: Возможно человек решил написать какой-либо `watcher`, чего сразу гнать-то?

Comment: Не гоню, интересно самому, может и необходимости такой нет, может я не так его понимаю. Ваш ответ отлично демонстрирует, что я ничего не понимаю. Он работает!

Comment: Приведи пример кода, чтобы стало ясно, что и где ты хочешь получить

Comment: Надобности наверное то и нет, т.к. делаю видимо велосипед. Мысль была такая - во Вью проекте создал компонент ActionsBar, в него передаю объект ActionsModel, в нем какие то общие переменные, а непосредственно действия реализованы в наборе классов типа SomeAction c методами exec, isDisable. В модели методы  sameAction() {if (this.actionsMap.has(name)) return this.actionsMap.get(name) else {const Action = await import('./actions/' + name);
let action = new Action.default; this.actionsMap.set(name, action);return action;} Думал можно ли как то получать непосредственно в коде название функции.

Comment: добавь в сам вопрос пример того, что ты хочешь получить. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое возможно реализовать через `Proxy`:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, surname) {
    this.name = name
    this.surname = surname
  }

  fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`
  }
}

let user = new User("Mark", "Minerov")

user = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, property) {
    if (typeof target[property] === 'function') {
      console.log(`function ${property} was called!`)
    }

    return target[property]
  }
})

console.log(user.fullName())
```

Comment: И все же, разве Proxy не перехватывает запрос к целевому объекту, возвращая название метода (property), к которому было обращение если это property == 'function'? Можно ли сказать, что доступ к этому имени осуществился из "кода метода"?